# Angular 9.1.0. "mat-table" won't load dataSource from GET Rest Api

Tags: angular, api, undefined, datasource, mat-table

I'm trying to load data into mat-table, but when I console.log the dataSource I'm trying to load, it says the data is undefined.

[Link To Image Of Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuuPZ.png)

Object I retrieved is nested.
[API Request](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR)

I'm following official tutorial from Angular website and it's [material table examples](https://stackblitz.com/angular/kelxobmpnmp?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-http-example.ts). 
Also accessible from here [Table retrieving data through HTTP](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

**Reposnse:**

```
{"BTC":{"USD":8682.55,"EUR":7851.55},"ETH":{"USD":224.8,"EUR":203.77}}
```

This is my attempt so far:
( You will notice, ngAfterViewInit() is not used, that is due to user input Api has to wait for, I'm still tinkering around with it ).

**HTML:**

```
<button (click)="removeList()">Reset</button>
<button (click)="initialiseTableData()">Display Value</button>


<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-loading-shade" *ngIf="isLoadingResults">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoadingResults"></mat-spinner>
  </div>
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="example-table" matSort matSortActive="created" matSortDisableClear
    matSortDirection="asc">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="cryptocurrency">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Cryptocurrency</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.items.cryptovalue }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="currency">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Currency</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.items.currency }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator [length]="resultsLength" [pageSize]="30">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**And this is my .ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { merge, Observable, of as observableOf } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, startWith, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSortModule, MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatPaginatorModule, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';


export interface TableDataApi {
  items: Tabledata[];
  total_count: number;
}

export interface Tabledata {
  cryptovalue: {
    currency: string;
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-crypto-chooser',
  templateUrl: './crypto-chooser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crypto-chooser.component.css']
})

export class CryptoChooserComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private client: HttpClient) { }

  displayedColumns = ['cryptocurrency', 'currency'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  resultsLength = 0;
  isLoadingResults = false;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  initialiseTableData() {
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);

    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = true;
          return this.getCoins();
        }),
        map(data => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.resultsLength = data.total_count;
          return data.items;
        }),
        catchError(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          return observableOf([]);
        })
      ).subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data);
    console.log(this.dataSource);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  }

  getCoins(): Observable<TableDataApi> {
    this.generateUrl();
    return this.client.get<TableDataApi>(this.urlComplete, this.httpHeader);
  }
```

Comment: Try to print your data on subscribe method. Do this `.subscribe(data => {console.log(data); this.dataSource.data = data;});` Can you see your data that way?

Comment: With "new MatTableDataSource();" , it would give me just "undefined".

Comment: if you use the fragment of code that I commented before `console.log(data);` shows undefined? or shows the API payload?

Comment: Yes, with the dataSource: Tabledata[] = [], it gives me undefined.

Comment: Can you print on the map operator the data variable?
`map(data => {
          console.info('what is data?', data);
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.resultsLength = data.total_count;
          return data.items;
        }),`

Comment: In console.info I get this : What is data?  
{XRP: {…}, LTC: {…}, USDT: {…}}
XRP: {EUR: 0.2145}
LTC: {EUR: 54.36}
USDT: {EUR: 0.9068}
__proto__: Object, it gives me an object, and in the subscribe section of console I get undefined. I think it's not mapping the object correctly ?

Comment: It is correct, you're receiving an object from your getCoins method, look at my answer, try to do what I said in order to fix your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read some documentation about the material table data source API [Angular Material API Table Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api) and they say the following:

> The table's source of data, which can be provided in three ways (in order of complexity):
>
> Simple data array (each object represents one table row).
>
> Stream that emits a data array each time the array changes.
>
> DataSource object that implements the connect/disconnect interface.

You can use the first way (Simple data array).

Try doing this in order to use a simple data array instead of a matTableDataSource object.

```js
// use simple array instead of new MatTableDataSource()
// and define your interface later, for the moments we will use any
dataSource: any[] = [];
```

And here you have to modify your subscribe method in order to assign the response into dataSource variable that now it is an simple array.

```js
  initialiseTableData() {
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);

    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = true;
          return this.getCoins();
        }),
        map(data => {
          console.info('data is an object!', data);
          this.resultsLength = 0; // fix this later
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          // here, data has total_count and items attributes?
          // this.resultsLength = data.total_count;
          // I think data is an object because you're getting
          // an object as response, you're not getting a TableDataApi
          // structure
          return data;
        }),
        catchError(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          return observableOf([]);
        })
      ).subscribe(data => {
        // data is an object, is not an array
        // but your dataSource variable needs to be an array, so
        // you have to add data into [] in order to create an array
        // with your payload
        this.dataSource = [data]; // <- assign data to dataSource
        console.info('an array with my object', this.dataSource);
      });
  }
```

Now you have added an interface with items and totalCount attributes, I don't know why you did this because your HTTP request actually has an object payload, that is to say:
this is your payload, it is an object. This object doesn't have totalCount or items attributes. You need to fix your interface.

Your data payload is:

`{"BTC":{"USD":8682.55,"EUR":7851.55},"ETH":{"USD":224.8,"EUR":203.77}}`

I write above the way to transform your object payload into an array, only add your data object into [].

Remove the interface and use any for the moments, but you need to define an interface with the correct structure later.

```js
  getCoins(): Observable<any> { // define interface with your correct structure
    this.generateUrl();
    return this.client.get<any>(this.urlComplete, this.httpHeader);
  }
```

Comment: Ok, I set the dataSource like you said, and updated the function to return the response in Tabledata interface like this:

getCoins(): Observable<Tabledata[]> {
    this.generateUrl();
    return this.client.get<Tabledata[]>(this.urlComplete, this.httpHeader);
  }

console.log on data is giving me an object like it's supposed to:

{LTC: {…}, USDT: {…}, BCH: {…}}
LTC: {EUR: 54.24}
USDT: {EUR: 0.9067}
BCH: {EUR: 284.24}

But I do receive an error : Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource

Which tells me that mapping failed ?

Comment: No, you have to leave your code the same way, only use `dataSource: Tabledata[] = [];` instead of `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();` because your getCoins method is correct, don't change it

Comment: I edited the answer because I found out some errors in your code.

Comment: Ok, cool I'm so close now, An array with my object 
[{…}]
0:
XRP: {EUR: 0.2144}
LTC: {EUR: 54.36}
USDT: {EUR: 0.908}
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0), Array of object is stored in the array for the dataSource ! But, it's still not showing data on table, it shows just a blank line.

Comment: Yes, it is correct because in your HTML code you're trying to get properties from {{ row.items.cryptovalue }} and your structure doesn't have these attributes.

Comment: You need to map your response (object) to the structure of what you want to.